# What model of bike does Alicia Vikander use in Tomb Raider (2018)?

Tags: identify-this-bike, movie

Does anyone recognise this model of bike? It has some stickers/decals with fictional logos, but I couldn't find any brands/marks on the bike itself ([more images](http://raidingtheglobe.com/news/new-tomb-raider-set-pics-london-bike-courier-lara)):

[image]

---

**Note:** The fox tail and paint can are from a 'fox hunt' game/race in the film. See [here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-LARA-CROFT-ALICIA-VIKANDER-SCREEN-USED-COURIER-FOX-TAIL-RACE-SET/312110137476?hash=item48ab36c084:g:QrwAAOSwC6Ra0OqD).

Comment: I would guess they intentionally gave her a bike with an assortment of parts, to make the bike a bit more interesting.  And using a non-derailleur drive simplifies life for filming, in addition to looking and being cleaner.

Comment: The reason to have no recognizable brand is usually that none of the brands in question were willing to pay for it.

Comment: http://www.sebikes.com/archive/2016/tripel4

Comment: @R.Chung that's an awesome find - you should make that an answer.

Comment: She's wearing a Giro Synthe aero helmet.

Comment: The bike race scene is fun. It goes downhill quickly after that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Details original Bike used in the Tomb Raider movie 2018:  SE Bikes Tripel, Saddle Books Champion Standard B17, Vera Citywide tire - SE Bikes logo on the front of the frame -  handle grips purple - red pedal - Rear tire is possibly Kenda K-152. Kenda road tire in yellow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZliON.jpg)
[image: The Bike][image: Bike detail]
[image]

[image]

[image: SE Bikes Tripel]

[image: SE Bikes logo]details of bike[image]

[![][9]][9]

[image: numbers seen on tire]

[image: Compare to Kenda K-152. Kenda road tire in yellow in last picture.]

[image: Tire threads appear to match the Kenda K152 tire]
[image]

[image: Tire Thread comparison]

Comment: Those are utterly generic grips and don't really indicate anything, sorry.  However that's a good extra still photo that shows more detail than the original ones.

Comment: This should be edited into the question -- this does nothing to answer the question.

Comment: This settles the question about tires: for some reason or other, it is a trainer tire.

Comment: The markings look similar to the Kenda. K-152.road tire in yellow.



622x25.

28 ".

Comment: I added the last picture above of the Kenda K-152 numbers that match the tire from the movie bike

Comment: K-152 has strong herringbone pattern that the bike on film doesn't have. The numbers are just tire size and do not identify anything.

Comment: the movie tire is marked  k-152-909 ( or 999)  on the top right of the 2nd from last photo

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01M2900WT/    also the Kenda 176 has smother sides https://www.amazon.com/Kenda-Fixie-Fixed-Bicycle-Yellow/dp/B00GMQXM9W

Comment: @teadrinker your ebay link was dead - deleted, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Parts identified:

- 3 or 8 speed Shimano Internally Geared Hub in rear wheel, connected to Shimano revoshift shifter on the right hand.
- Brooks saddle based on the badge on the back.
- "Citiwide" brand front tyre (can't find this brand mentioned on the web)
- Dual pivot rim brakes - They look curiously solid and thick.
  Noted its a right-hand front-brake set up, because Lara Croft is English and these scenes are set in London where RHF is standard.
- Old-school Axle Nuts, not a QR on the front wheel.  This suggests an older bike or one used where stealing parts is possible.

Unknown accessories:

- Rear parcel rack - assume its to do with being a fast-food delivery courier.
- <s>Why the paint can?  Looks like a home-made pannier?</s>  **No** it's part of the plot.
- <s>Why the fox tail? It is not visible enough to be like a chopper-flag.</s> **No** it's also part of the plot.
- Why the yellow tyre?  **Film** Make her stand out from the background a bit more, help the audience identify her on screen easier.

<s>I don't think it's a specific brand - it's a prop made up from various parts, and decorated with stickers.</s>  **No** See R.Chung's answer.

Comment: Thanks for this effort! The paint can and fox tail are temporary custom elements - in the film, there is a 'fox hunt' on bikes across London where one cyclist has a tail and a can (with a hole) which leaks paint, providing a 'trail' for the 'hounds' (other cyclists) who pursue (if a 'hound' catches the tail, they win the prize-money; if the 'fox' evades all capture, they win it). I'm not sure why the tire is yellow. There is a scene where Alicia uses the front brake to stop in an 'endo' position. The brakes may have been mirrored to make this 'stunt' easier for the actor?

Comment: Right-hand front braking is common in the UK. (Also, motorbike riders sometimes switch brakes, to match the front brake on motorbikes, but as she is British the former should be the reason here). I would have guessed the hub to be 3 speed, do 8 speed Shimano hubs exist with the visible external part? The did give her decent pedals.

Comment: I think the yellow tire has to do  with the fox hunt thing. See [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/53797/does-the-fox-hunt-game-exist-professionally).  It goes with the paint and the fox tail.

Comment: Without having seen the movie, the yellow tire could just have the purpose to make the main character easier to spot for the audience in more chaotic or wide shots.

Comment: @linac Thank you - I assumed it was an american/hollywood movie.

Comment: @Kibbee She uses the same bike with yellow rear tyre earlier in the film (before she is aware of/participates in the fox hunt), so it's probably a character quirk/visual cue/visual aid. A person on Reddit suggested it was a [trainer specific tyre](https://www.amazon.com/CycleOps-9711-Trainer-Tire-Yellow/dp/B00EQAN994/).

Comment: Regarding the tire: I'm not saying it's not a trainer specific tire, but before Continental GP4000S was released road bike tires used to be every color of rainbow. It wouldn't be out of place for a messenger to have old racing parts on her bike. But in the film, it's probably to identify the bike and rider at a glance.

Comment: If anyone is curious, [the](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-LARA-CROFT-ALICIA-VIKANDER-SCREEN-WORN-HELMET-GLOVES-SHOES-CH-4/142756593968) [helmet](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-LARA-CROFT-ALICIA-VIKANDER-SCREEN-WORN-HELMET-GLOVES-CH-2-3/312089002925) is a Giro, possibly a [Synthe](http://www.giro.com/eu_en/products/women/helmets/aero-tri/synthetm-mips.html#gid=24778), with the main logos sanded/filled/painted.

Answer (score 1):

in response to comment by ukemi : Helmet is Rapha Giro Synthe[image: Rapha Synthe Helmet]
With refernce to "Unknowns" above : Panier Rack is Halfords https://www.halfords.com/cycling/bike-accessories/bike-pannier-racks/halfords-essentials-alloy-pannier-rack[image: panier rack]

Comment: OK but pannier racks are after-market accessories and the helmet isn't part of the bike, so I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33253)

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov How does it answer the question? The question asks "What is this bike?" and this post identifies a helmet and a pannier rack.

Answer (score 1):

From [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bicycling/comments/8bxykc/does_anyone_recognise_the_model_of_bike_used_by/):

> 2016ish SE Bikes Tripel.

> Vera CityWide are Fuji eom tires, not sure that's the same?

> > Why the yellow tyre?
>
> Im pretty sure thats a trainer specific tire [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EQAN994)

> Looks like a fairly basic steel frame with 3-speed nexus hub. Pretty common for a lot of retailers to stock a bike like this, without a logo on the frame its hard work to say which exactly but they are all pretty much the same. For example a Reid harrier 3-speed

Answer (score -5):

I can assume that the bike was made specifically for the movie and you can not buy it for yourself. For most films, exclusive things are done.

Comment: It has already been identified as SE Bikes Tripel.

Comment: That's a fair point and often movie-things are done that way.  The bike's brand name is not blatantly placed on-screen as a product placement, but its not going to be custom-built different and unique for the movie.

Comment: Often it also works the other way: building props from scratch is difficult and expensive, so store-bought objects are used instead. For some examples, check this list: https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/the-store-bought-items-used-as-sci-fi-movie-props-a7186916.html